# I need a topc Idea for my math project

Tags: probability, statistics

I am taking a class in college called applied math in the modern world.  For this project we have to choose one of the math topic's we've discussed and relate it to a true story such as an event. I have no proposal Idea's so far. I'm choosing between probability and statistics. Keep in mind this is a 123 class and so keep suggestions simple, I am not a math major.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about looking at the effect of card counting on Blackjack probabilities. The story part could be the MIT Blackjack Team: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_Blackjack_Team

Comment: Thank you Sir !

Comment: I proposed this idea with my professor and he said I needed to be more specific. What do you mean by the effects of card counting ? like whether it's a good or bad ?

Comment: 'Good or bad' sounds like a moral question which is beyond probability theory. It increases the chances of winning for the Blackjack player which is a probabilistic question and therefore 'good' for their odds of winning

Comment: I decided to re focus my question to 
whether casino's should limit the amount of decks they use in a game of blackjack"

Answer (score 1):

Get some data from your college about the enrollment in the past and make a linear regression to forecast the future enrollment. You need to get at least 20 years of data to have a good equation.

You may collect data about different majors as well and see which majors are becoming more popular and which ones are loosing popularity.
Based on your data make recommendation to your college administrators regarding possible improvements.

Comment: Do you have something more simple ? I'm in Math 123, were not studying linear regression.

Comment: Play with  probability of putting different  color  marbles in  boxes. Like you have twenty marbles of three colors. What is the probability of .....

Comment: Can you give me an event ? My professor want's something from an event.

Comment: I have given you enough hint. you have to do the rest.

Comment: I apologize maybe I wasn't being specific, I meant like a recent new's item or worldly event. Thanks again !